# Does a turbine experience a countering electromagnetic force while it induces a voltage?

Tags: induction

I am assuming yes, because of the law of conservation of energy. A certain amount of energy is required to turn a turbine. So if we want a turbine to spin as well as induce a voltage, then more energy will be required to do so. I suspect the turning of the turbine is impeded by an emf, which requires more energy to push through, compared to a situation where we were just looking to spin a turbine without wanting to induce a voltage.

Comment: a turbine does not generate electric current ... a turbine generates rotating force

Comment: The turbine does counter an torque that is produced by an electromagnetic force...but that electromagnetic force is produced in the generator it is connected to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is asked as is a yes or no question about a poorly described complex system.

Comment: Once the description of the system is clearly described, the answer is yes, the law of conservation of energy is the key to understanding all such questions.

Comment: if a turbine connected to a permanent magnet generator spins, then it will induce a voltage, proportional to the rotation speed. If a load draws current from the generator, then the generator will create a torque back on the turbine, proportional to the current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The turbine needs to develop sufficient torque to overcome the electromagnetic forces within the generator.

With a turbine alone, the hydraulic energy requirement would be to just rotate it at the desired RPM. To that would be added the energy required to keep the electrically unloaded generator rotating at the same RPM. The final addition would be the energy required to feed the electrical load, with the generator maintaining the same RPM.

The ultimate power (torque at the desired RPM), required to be generated by the turbine, would be decided by the electrical load.

The rate of flow of the fluid in the hydraulic system would determine the power that could be generated by the turbine.

Answer (score 1):

> *Does a turbine experience a countering electromagnetic force while it
>   induces a voltage?*

No it doesn't unless that induced voltage is driving a load and circulating a current AND the load is resistive i.e. it consumes power.